# MVC4 Bundling Wildcards - * vs. {version}

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I understand and fully appreciate the new bundle wildcard {version} regex, as it will continue to pick up your script and style libraries even after updating, etc.  The problem is that I cannot get it to work effectively.

I had previously use the following notation to pick up my jQuery scripts:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
            "~/Scripts/jquery-1.*"));
```

and it would pick up all files matching the asterisk wildcard.

But when I tried the following:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

I noticed that the jQuery file was not written out to the _Layout.cshtml page.

NOTE - I am indeed using the following HTML code for both examples:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
```

When I use the first example above (" * ") notation the following is written to the page:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However when I use the "{version}" notation, there is merely an empty space where the library should be written.  This pertains to both jquery files as well as the associated CSS stylesheets.

It does not matter whether I am compiling for DEBUG or RELEASE mode.  The results are the same.  Obviously in release mode I'll get the optimized version when using the "*" notation:

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=VUv2YOeuOgHad-FHZ-vGMDu9wN1j9VZGifI1SBUUSMs1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So being the perfectionist that all developers are, I would greatly like to see the {version} notation work for me, as I do keep up to date on new releases and would like this control on my deployments.

Any insight into what I may be doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Comment: What version of .Net are you running the project under? I believe that there is a limitation to .net 4.5 for the {version} keyword.

Comment: Hi John, I am indeed using the .Net 4.5 framework, and perhaps that is where some of the issues come from.  I would think it's been out long enough to have it working by now, although I have not checked since the * notation works and allows me to move forward.

Comment: Do you have both a .min.js and .js version of the jQuery file in the solution? In previous versions of Web optimisation there was an assumption around use of .min files in release mode and files without the .min in debug even if the file did not exist. This behaviour has been changed in later versions. See http://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/workitem/32. I'm not sure if this was your issue as the filename you cite is without the .min in the name.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization and related NuGet packages: Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure, WebGrease, Antlr. Check not just "nuget.org" tab, but also "All".